# Windows 10 screenshot not working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot, reset

I recently reset my pc cuz of some problems. Screenshot worked fine then though, but now dosen't work.
I tried:

1. PrintScreen
2. Win + PrintScreen
3. Ctrl + PrintScreen
4. Alt + PrintScreen
5. Fn + PrintScreen
6. Fn + Win + PrintScreen
7. Alt + Win + PrintScreen
8. Ctrl + Win + PrintScreen
9. Win + Shift + PrintScreen

Have tried Googling but no luck. Please help.
Note: Win + Shift + S takes a snip of the screen, ik about that. I want to save it as screen shot in C:\Users<User Name>\Pictures\Screenshots like it was before the reset.

Comment: The default behavior for Windows 10 seems to be to use Win+Shift+S for a screen print, which places a copy of the screen (or a selected area) on the clipboard.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. if you have a third-party tool such as AutoHotKey, stop it and test again - it might be stealing keypress. 2. Use DISM and SFC to repair Windows See https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/repair-windows-10-using-dism-sfc/

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 20H2 and beyond (and possibly earlier), use:

WinKey Shift  S

That is the default setup, launches Snip 'n Sketch, allows you to capture whatever area on the screen.

Once you have captured a section, Notification allows you to open, edit and save to a location of your choice.

You did a reset and this (above) is the default behavior.

Win Shift S also does not interfere with other software here including SnagIt screen capture software.

It is best (my view) that you use Winkey Shift S to launch Snip 'n Sketch. It does not interfere with anything so far as I know.

You can change the Winkey Shift S to PrtScr in Accessibility features if you find that helpful

[Change Snin 'n Sketch launch key](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/screenshot-portion-screen-windows-10-winkey-shift-s/)

> If you think the three keys combo Winkey + Shift + S is tough to
> operate, you can choose to have your PrtScn key open the new snipping
> bar, instead of Winkey + Shift + S. To do so:
>
> Click Start → Settings → Ease of Access → Keyboard → Use the PrtScn
> button to open screen snipping